# I put NSString in NSUUID and I log an wrong UUID iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ibeacon, nsuuid

I work with iBeacon and I want to monitor many beacons together.
I make a for(NSDictionary *iBeacon in iBeacons) to have all iBeacons I need.
In each loop, I try to put NSString into an NSUUID like this :

```
NSString *uuid = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:iBeacon[@"UUID"]];
NSLog(@"UUID = %@",uuid);//first log
NSUUID *proximityUUID = [[NSUUID UUID] initWithUUIDString:uuid];
NSLog(@"proximityUUID = %@",proximityUUID);//Second log
```

When I look my log I see :

```
UUID = 5A4BCFCE-174E-4BAC-A814-092E77F6B7E5
proximityUUID = <__NSConcreteUUID 0x16ec5db0> 5A4BCFCE-174E-4BAC-A814-092E77F6B7E5
```

I would like that UUID equal proximityUUID, I dont understand why `<__NSConcreteUUID 0x16ec5db0>` is added?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<__NSConcreteUUID 0x16ec5db0>` is just some information about the object. It is an instance of `__NSConcreteUUID` (a concrete subclass of `NSUUID`) and it's pointer is stored at the memory address `0x16ec5db0`. to get the UUID value itself, do

```
NSLog(@"proximityUUID = %@",proximityUUID.UUIDString)
```

Answer (score 1):

`proximityUUID` is `NSUUID`, not `NSString`.

Instead, you should use `UUIDString` method.

```
NSLog(@"proximityUUID = %@", [proximityUUID UUIDString]); //Second log
```